# How to see the duration of a FaceTime call?

Tags: iphone, ios, facetime

The following Apple resource says the duration should be available by clicking the "I". But I do not see it

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8360458

> When you’re doing a FaceTime video call, you’re unable to see the duration of the call until the call has ended. Once it has concluded, you can go into your call log and tap the “i” to the right of the FaceTime call to view the duration.

However as shown that information is not actually available

[image]

Is there any way to get that info?

**Update**  I posted the wrong screenshot (this one was *Cancelled* ) . But I have checked a number calls including some that took double digit minutes.  They all looked like this (except for the *Cancelled Facetime* message).  There are no duration / minutes on any of the calls.

Comment: Is there a way to see this info on macOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On iOS 14, the FaceTime calls show up like cellular phone calls. Open the phone app, tap recents at the bottom navigation area and find the call in question.

[image: Duration and data for completed FaceTime calls.]

Duration and data used is listed for completed calls.

Comment: Works in iOS 15 too.   I thought this was yet another feature Apple had stolen (like Siri history).  I remember this info being easier to find/see for all calls.  Is there a way to see this info on macOS?  Can't find it.

Comment: That would make an excellent follow on question @WHO'sNoToOldRx4CovidIsMurder I haven’t thought to check

Comment: Agreed. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432294/how-can-i-see-the-duration-of-my-facetime-calls-on-macos-11