# How can I see the duration of my FaceTime calls on macOS 11+?

Tags: macos, facetime

How can I see the duration of my FaceTime calls on macOS 11+?

This is a follow-up to [How to see the duration of a FaceTime call?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423100/how-to-see-the-duration-of-a-facetime-call/423144?noredirect=1#comment619525_423144)

I remember this info being easier to find/see for all Facetime calls.
Is this yet another feature Apple has stolen away (like Siri history on iPhone)?

Comment: Thank you for posting this as a clear question.